# git push access denied

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-push

I think I put my credentials wrong when doing git push to a remote https, because I wasn't sure which credentials to use.

Now everytime that I try it again, I get the error:

> remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied fatal: Authentication failed for
>   'https://

What credentials should I use and how can I try it again?

Comment: git push -u origin master

Comment: Since you're talking to GitHub, one sanity check you may do is to try logging in directly to GitHub using the credentials.  If they don't work at all, then I'm not suprised by your current observations.

Comment: @slon I don't think that would resolve an authentication error, and the OP did not tell us that this is the first time he is pushing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If she is pushing first time, there will be alot of things to check first, she sounds like she just did a mistake and doesn't get new prompt again for credentials. And I am totally agree with your suggestion to check credentials on browser to make sure what is wrong and right.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you're right. That's what happens. I'm logged in GitHub from my browser. I just need to be able to retry from the Git Bash

Answer (score 1):

if it's an existing project... navigate in Git Bash console window to your project's root. Type the following only to create the repository locally.

```
git init       (only do this when you first set up repository)
```

Then

```
git add YourFileName
```

or

```
git add *     (to add the whole directory and subdirectories)
```

Then

```
git commit -m "type some comments here within quotes"
```

(At this point log into github's website and create a repository ONLY if you are just setting up the repository for the first time -- copy and paste the "git remote add origin master url" from the page loads after creating the repo. It's look something like this:

```
git remote add origin https....    (only do this the when you first set up repository)
```

Then

```
git push origin master
```

FROM NOW ON.. any time you make changes that need to be added... just do this:

```
git add YourFileName
git commit -m "some comments about the changes made"
git push origin master
```

You will then see your changes reflected on Github's servers when you log in and look at your repository.

This is bare minimum... Also it's best NOT to initialize with a README or ignore file until all of this is done and working properly.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very useful. I just have a problem: I already have an origin so I created a new one "git remote add gitlab https://gitlab.com/username/name.git" and then I do "git push gitlab master" and I get the error "error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.com/username/name.git". what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ah don’t do “git push gitlab master”. Just do “git push origin master”

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link which explains how to connect you System to GitHub through ssh

https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/

and Successful connection run

> git push origin master

Comment: can I not use Git Bash?

Comment: You Can. Initially when git developed git was made In/for  Linux/Unix system. In Order to Support In windows which don't contain bash shell, They came up with git Blash. So All the commands will be the same  In windows, Unix & Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your ideas, after trying, I found that I already had an origin added, so after deleting my GitLab account and created it again to put the right credentials, these are the steps I followed:

Created a new remote git repository:

```
git remote add gitlab https://gitlab.com/myusername/myproject.git
```

check my remote repositories:

```
git remote -v
```

I also created a branch in the remote gitLab with the same name of my local branch did:

```
git pull gitlab mybranch --allow-unrelated-histories
```

> 1. press "i"
> 2. write your merge message.
> 3. press "esc"
> 4. write ":wq"
> 5. then press enter.

```
git push gitlab mybranch
```

I hope this may be useful.